# debug mode : MACDOC;TRDEBG USAGE

Tags: debugging, maxima, wxmaxima

I try to understand how to use the debug mode in wxmaxima. In the documentation is specified "See MACDOC;TRDEBG USAGE for more information. Consult GJC for more help".

I can't find the reference to "MACDOC;TRDEBG USAGE" nor  "GJC". Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that's a good one. I believe GJC is George J. Carrette (?) who worked on Macsyma (the precursor to Maxima) about 40 years ago. `MACDOC;TRDEBUG USAGE` is a reference to a file on an ancient filesystem. There may be a file named `trdebug.usg` or something like that floating around; I haven't looked.

I think you will find most or all of the existing documentation for debugging in the section titled "Debugging" in the reference manual. Here it is online: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_38.html I think that the same documentation is also included in wxMaxima.

By the way, where did you find the reference to MACDOC?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the link. I find this reference in a french translation (2003) of the W. Shelter manual. You can find it on the link below https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1wIupwpnnAhWhz4UKHcnnBhcQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmichel.gosse.free.fr%2Fdocumentation%2Ffichiers%2Fmaximafr.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2wacv3X3-L4WalYQlYBHkW